# Why aren't custom performance counters being recorded by my PerfMon data collector set?

Tags: perfmon

I have six custom performance counters that were created by a .NET app. When I open Performance Monitor and add them to the live view, those counters are displayed correctly. I can see the values I expect in the live graph.

I created a user defined data collector set that records some built-in counters like "Processor\% Processor Time" and "Memory\Available MBytes" as well as the custom performance counters. Everything appears to work correctly when I save it and start it.

When I let it run for a while and then restart the data collector and open the BLG file, it shows all the built-in counters correctly, but my custom counters are not available. They aren't listed in the "Available Counters" list. Why can't perfmon select my custom counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem. I created the new counters and added them to an existing data collector set in the PerfMon UI, but the app had not actually created any instances yet. So the counters I added were defined as "\MyApp:Perf\*" instead of "\MyApp:Perf(*)\*".

Now that the app has been logging data for a while, I removed and re-added the counters, and they worked this time. I'm pretty sure that if I used logman to create the data collector set with "\MyApp:Perf(*)\*" explicitly specified, that would have worked too.